# PowerShell running functions from .ps1 with multiple parameters

Tags: function, powershell, parameters, call

I'm trying to run a function that is located within a .ps1 file. The function accepts two parameters that could be either a string or int. Here is my code:

Filename: SetFarmProp.ps1

```
Function SetFarm ($property_name, $property_value) `
{
    $farm = Get-SPFarm

    $farm.Properties.Add($property_name, $property_value)

    $farm.properties
}
```

When I go into my PowerShell session and type in

```
.\SetFarmProp.ps1
SetFarm "testkey" "testvalue1"
```

I get an error saying that the "SetFarm" is not a recognized name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try dot sourcing:

```
. .\SetFarmProp.ps1
SetFarm "testkey" "testvalue1"
```

Or just:

```
.\SetFarmProp.ps1 "testkey" "testvalue1"
```

If you modify your .ps1 file as:

```
param ($property_name, $property_value)
{
    $farm = Get-SPFarm

    $farm.Properties.Add($property_name, $property_value)

    $farm.properties
}
```